# Mount drive and iis

Tags: php, linux, windows, iis, mount

having problem when trying to access mount drive from iis.

currently we have 2 server,

- 1 web-server (windows iis, php)
- 1 file-server (linux)

we need to store file at file-server.
we are able to mount linux folder to windows.

but get false when doing in php:

```
var_dump(file_exists("Z:/")); //false

var_dump('//image-server-asia1/foldername'); //false
```

what should i do to make iis able to read the mount drive?

[mounted drive at windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SbWH.png)